# Выдает None при парсинге страницы python bs4

Tags: python-3.x, requests, bs4, lxml

Появилась такая проблема что парсер просто не находит данные хотя на странице они есть. Вот сам код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests 

url = 'https://docdoc.ru/doctor'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')

def name():
    for i in soup.find_all('a'):
        name = soup.find('a', {'class':'DoctorListPageCardDetails__link_1cVC'}) 
        print(name)

name()
```

Пока искал ответы понял что нужно перейти на selenium. Но особого желания этого делать нет.

Comment: Вот вам не большая подказка print(soup.find('doctor-list-page') если вы ее не осилите используйте selenium.

Comment: Получается надо будет просто извлечь имена из этого списка?